# Antlr Grammar not able to give required AST

Tags: java, antlr, grammar

I have a set of key word(like IF, FOR, etc), all of those in normal programming language. Each statement ends with a ';'.
The problem I am facing is that I am unable to write a grammar for print statements.
Each print statement starts with a ':'. I have skipped all end of line characters and spaces.
I face a challenge if I have continuous print statements.

Eg:

```
:$name This is first line 
:This is second line
```

My grammar:

```
stmt : printStmt+
   printStmt: ':' printlite;
   printlite : (anychar|('$' identifier))+;
   anychar: ~(allKeywords) ;
```

The AST contains
                 [AST output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FeMVJ.jpg)

I have tried adding EOL at the end of any char, printlite, printstmt but nothing seemed to work. The output expected is 2 printStmt nodes. I have all '\r \n' skipped.

for better understanding, this is the piece I am trying to parse :

```
FUNCTION xyz(STRING searchStr)
{   
    :Error while reading a file $name
    abc();
}
```

My grammar has all white spaces and end of line character skipped.
Please suggest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not entirely clear what you are trying to achieve, but the grammar below ...

```
main : statement+;
statement: ':' (identifier|other_words)+ CR*;
identifier : '$' IDENTIFIER;
other_words : ~(CR)+ ;

IDENTIFIER : [A-Za-z]+ ;
CR : '\r'? '\n' ;

WS : [ \t]+ -> skip ;
```

... produces the following AST with your example input :

[image: AST for example text]

Comment: Just a side not for the OP: by "promoting" the $ prepended rule to the parser, input like `$ foo` (a space between between `$` and `foo`), will be treated the same as `$foo` (without a space). Maybe that is what the OP wants, maybe not.

Comment: Hi @Marc Q. I might not be clear with my question. Hence I have updated it. I wanted my printstmt to end with the line since I do not have any delimiter which marks the end like a ";". Also I have skipped End Of line characters.

Comment: @BharatJain Probably the Enf-Of-Line skipping is your problem. If the Lexer skips EOLs, the parser cannot use them as delimiters. Can you try without skipping?

Comment: @MarcQ. Thank you. I used a MultiToken Stream and only skipped EOLs for where I do not require. I enabled the EOLs for print statements and it worked.